# how to access wordpress dropdown menu value in template file

Tags: wordpress

I have frontend drop down  menu selection of a custom field. It is a list of property measurement units. When user selects an option, I want to change measurement units of all posts on that page to user selected value. I am displaying properties list. So basically there are properties with different measurement units. So I want to change the each property unit to user selected option. How do I do this?? 
Any body know the solution??

Comment: as you may know already, this site is to help you with existing code, not to write you new one, so pls provide us with the code you've tried already, and we'll be happy to help...

Comment: I just want to know how and logic behind that. I dont need code. And I also want to know is it possible or not??

Answer (score 0):

Add a specific class name to the elements of measurement units consistently throughout the site. Then append an event handler to your drop-down menu items and update the above elements with the specific class names according to the selection made in the drop-down.